# Error building in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, build, linker

I have a main function, which looks like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include "mins_ndim.h"
#include "ObjectiveFunction.h"

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {

  ObjectiveFunction objective;
  Frprmn<ObjectiveFunction> frprmn(objective);
  std::vector<double> p(2);
  p[0]=7; p[1]=3;
  frprmn.eat();
}
```

but this gives me the error:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "Frprmn<ObjectiveFunction>::eat()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`eat()` is listed in the struct definition of Frprmn in `mins_ndim.h` and defined in `mins_ndim.cpp`.  if I define it in `mins_ndim.h` then I don't get this error.  I assume this is something to do with linking, but I don't know how I can get xcode to sort it out?!

Comment: The file with your main can't see `mins_ndim.cpp`, so if you define `eat()` there, you get an undefined symbol.

Comment: so how can I use the functions I define in the .cpp file?  the function is listed in the header file, so I though it should be accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitions of member functions of class templates must be visible to the compiler when they are used. When the compiler encounters `frprmn.eat();` it has not seen the implementation of `eat` (it has only seen the declaration in `mins_ndim.h`) and so cannot generate the appropriate code.

Remember that a template is essentially a piece of code that the compiler must instantiate with the template types replaced with the appropriate template arguments. The compiler needs to be able to see the implementation of `eat` to be able to generate it with `ObjectiveFunction` as the template argument.

It is common practice to implement function templates or member functions of class templates in header files for this reason.

An alternative, if you want to keep the definition of the class template and its implementation separate, is to include the implementation file at the *bottom* of the header file. This inverts the typical method of inclusion. To make this clearer, it's common to name the implementation file with the `.tpp` extension (`t` for template). This makes it more obvious which files are including which.

Comment: so if I'm using a class template, there's no way to keep the implementation and declaration in separate files (as I would tend to do for non-template classes)?

Comment: @tiswas Other than the little trick I described in my last paragraph, no. The template implementations must be included in any file that wants to use them. Just the declaration won't do.